# Slow query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have following query which I am trying to optimize, the query runs in 3 seconds if I remove the join condition **I.ident_id in (select distinct(ident_id) from MISSING_Images miss )** from below query but with this I takes 3 mins to execute.

```
SELECT IDENT_ID
   FROM tbl_IDENT I
            JOIN tbl_TA AN ON (AN.IDENT_ID = I.IDENT_ID and AN.anchor_point = I.c_id)
            JOIN tbl_AB A ON (A.A_ID = I.A_ID)
            JOIN tbl_FULL_ARCHIVE FT ON (FT.ARCHIVE_ID = I.ARCHIVE_ID)
            WHERE (I.DATA_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' or I.DATA_STATUS = 'INACTIVE')
            AND 
            (
             I.FD = 'Y'
                OR


 I.ident_id in (select distinct(ident_id) from MISSING_Images miss where substr(miss.NAME, 0, INSTR(miss.NAME, '.',-1,1)) in (SELECT substr(IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1)) FROM IMAGES ))
```

);

**select distinct(ident_id) from MISSING_Images miss** return 2000 records and main tbl_IDENT has over 100,000 record. I have the index created on I.ident_id

Any hint how to improve it. I am using oracle 10g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to replace

```
I.ident_id in (select distinct(ident_id) from MISSING_Images miss)
```

with

```
EXISTS (select 1 from MISSING_Images miss where miss.ident_id = I.ident_id)
```

And create an index on MISSING_Images.ident_id

**EDIT**: The most direct solution will be:

```
EXISTS (select 1 from MISSING_Images miss 
        where miss.ident_id = I.ident_id
          and exists (select 1 from images img 
                      where substr(img.IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(img.IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                            = substr(miss,NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                     )
        )
```

And create index-based indexes:

```
create index indx_name1 on images(substr(IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))); 
create index indx_name2 on MISSING_Images(substr(miss.NAME, 0, INSTR(miss.NAME, '.',-1,1)));
```

Take a note that such indexes can have a bad impact on insert/update operations on the undelying objects and require some additional space. In addition to that they don't work well with nulls.

Other choices:

```
EXISTS (select 1 from MISSING_Images miss join images img 
                        on substr(img.IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(img.IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                            = substr(miss,NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
        where miss.ident_id = I.ident_id
       )


EXISTS (select 1 from (select miss.ident_id MISSING_Images miss join images img 
                        on substr(img.IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(img.IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                            = substr(miss,NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                       ) sub        
        where sub.ident_id = I.ident_id
       )
```

Comment: I've seen some benchmarks on DB2 where "EXISTS" performs better than "IN", so it would not surprise me the same may be true on Oracle. That said, if you do not have an index on MISSING_Images.ident_id, creating that index will make a larger improvement.

Comment: Hi Mike, with index on MISSING_Images.ident_id things have imporved but  I have updated the question because I forgot to add the where clause in MISSING_Images which is using substr and  that seems to be an actual problem.

Comment: @atif How many images do you have? Is there any chance to store a foreign key on IMAGES in MISSING_Images instead of parsing and comparing names?

Comment: foreign key is not possible because user upload them in images table and we reprocess them in to jpgs (MISSING_Images)  so extension is different in both the tables  and that's why we are checking it via name without extension of images. There are about 10000 images.

Comment: @atif I've updated my answer. Function-based indexes is the most obvious solution (but not necessarily the best). Insert/update may be a bit slower, but it usually makes sense in real time systems with lots of inserts-updates.

Comment: Hi Mike, Created the indexes mentioned by you but no affcted. If I remove the where clause then it is faster  substr(img.IMG_NAME, 0, INSTR(img.IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))
                            = substr(miss,NAME, 0, INSTR(IMG_NAME, '.',-1,1))

Comment: Here is the execution plan when I am using where clause 

36 HASH JOIN SEMI  Cost: 172  Bytes: 45  Cardinality: 1           
   34 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE MISSING_Images Cost: 2  Bytes: 50  Cardinality: 2          
    33 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX MISSING_Images_IDENT_ID Cost: 1  Cardinality: 2         
   35 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN INDEX IMAGES_IMG_NAME Cost: 168  Bytes: 3,442,320  Cardinality: 172,116

Comment: Here is the plan when no where clause is used 

35 FILTER           
   33 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX MISSING_IMAGES_IDENT_ID Cost: 1  Bytes: 14  Cardinality: 2          
   34 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE IMAGES Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1

Comment: @atif Without WHERE it is fast because Oracle finds the first row and stops (exists). By looking on your plan I can say that you don't need function-based index on MISSING_Images (INDEX MISSING_Images_IDENT_ID works fine - I suppose it returns small number of rows). Also I think there are a lot of rows with different I.ident_id and for each you're checking IMAGES that's why INDEX FAST FULL SCAN is used.

Comment: @atif How long does it take now to execute the whole query?

Comment: 3 mins... without where clause 3 secs

Comment: @atif I've added some other choices. If it won't help - I give up.

Comment: @atif how did my query perform? Out of curiosity only.

Answer (score 1):

Try a union instead, to begin with?

```
SELECT IDENT_ID
FROM tbl_IDENT I
    JOIN tbl_TA AN ON AN.IDENT_ID = I.IDENT_ID AND AN.anchor_point = I.c_id
    JOIN tbl_AB A ON A.A_ID = I.A_ID
    JOIN tbl_FULL_ARCHIVE FT ON FT.ARCHIVE_ID = I.ARCHIVE_ID
WHERE 
    (I.DATA_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR I.DATA_STATUS = 'INACTIVE')
AND I.FD = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT IDENT_ID
FROM tbl_IDENT I
    JOIN tbl_TA AN ON AN.IDENT_ID = I.IDENT_ID AND AN.anchor_point = I.c_id
    JOIN tbl_AB A ON A.A_ID = I.A_ID
    JOIN tbl_FULL_ARCHIVE FT ON FT.ARCHIVE_ID = I.ARCHIVE_ID
    JOIN MISSING_Images miss ON I.ident_id = miss.ident_id
WHERE 
    I.DATA_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
OR I.DATA_STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
;
```

More improvements can surely be provided, but for that I'd need an explain plan of the query...

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `MISSING_Images(ident_id)`.

I would also suggest that you write the `where` clause as:

```
        WHERE I.DATA_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') AND
              (I.FD = 'Y' OR
               I.ident_id in (select ident_id from MISSING_Images miss)
              )
```

The `distinct` is unnecessary in an `in` subquery.  Also, `in` is easier to read (and write and maintain) then a list of individual comparisons.  The index should take care of performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can even combine the where filters in the join conditions 
like below

```
SELECT IDENT_ID
   FROM tbl_IDENT I
            JOIN tbl_TA AN ON (AN.IDENT_ID = I.IDENT_ID and AN.anchor_point = I.c_id)
            and I.DATA_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') AND
            I.FD = 'Y'
                OR
             I.ident_id in (select distinct(ident_id) from MISSING_Images miss)
            JOIN tbl_AB A ON (A.A_ID = I.A_ID)
            JOIN tbl_FULL_ARCHIVE FT ON (FT.ARCHIVE_ID = I.ARCHIVE_ID);
```

and even you can have exists clause with that (as @Multisync said) might result in better performance.